# html tengo un radio button con required pero no me muestra la alerta que esta vació el campo

Tags: html, radiobutton, required

Protegido

```
       <input type="radio" name="seguro" id="desgravamen" class="formulario__input " >
        <label for="desgravamen">Desgravamen</label>

        </div>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="formulario__submit" action="controlador" id="ap">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tenga valides la propiedad "required" debe estar dentro de un formulario. De este modo al realizar el submit ejecuta la validación de todos sus campos. Saludos!

```html
<form>
<input type="checkbox" required>Check required
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```